# What/Where is the value of E_CLR_ALREADY_STARTED?

Tags: clr, clr-hosting

The docs for [ICLRRuntimeHost::SetHostControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164414%28VS.80%29.aspx) claim that it can return E_CLR_ALREADY_STARTED. I have been unable to find a definition for this value. Ideally, I'd like to know what the appropriate header to include is (it does not appear to be in corerror.h) but if someone can provide me with the canonical value too I can live with that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to find it either and I'm usually pretty good at finding missing or misspelled constants. You could try calling the method after initializing the CLR and if it does in fact return the HRESULT that it's documented to return, you could just trace it. But it definitely seems like a documentation bug.

Comment: I've thought about doing that, but I'm a little leery of relying on the result of that, if it works.